# Jettison with json marshalling converting string data type to integer type, when value is numeric

Tags: java, json, rest, jakarta-ee, jettison

We are using jettison-1.3.3 for converting JaxB to Json.

We are facing an issue.
whenever I have a String property that contains all numbers (i.e. String phone="12345";), the JSON response will display it as a number (12345) without having the double quotes.

If the value is coming as 1234AS in this case returns with double quote.
How to fix this and making sure its always has double quotes.

Please help

Answer (score 3):

There are type converters in the jettison. By default it uses default type converter.
Default type convert removes double quotes if the value is numeric type.

To get always double quotes use SimpleConverter.

Create a system property - 
i.e 
System.setProperty("jettison.mapped.typeconverter.class", "org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.SimpleConverter");

So jettison uses simple converter and output values as string.

Comment: Hi Narendra Reddy, Thanks for the replay, i used jackson instead jettison and found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use the JSON-binding offered by MOXy for this use case.

**Domain Model (Root)**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    int number;
    String string;

}
```

**Specifying MOXy as your JSON-Binding Provider**

In a RESTful environment you can specify `MOXyJsonProvider` as the `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` for your JAX-RS application

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

In the standalone example below you can specify a `jaxb.properties` file in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html):

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo Code**

Below is a standalone example you can run to prove that everything works:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Root.class}, properties);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.number = 1234;
        root.string = "1234";

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
{
   "number" : 1234,
   "string" : "1234"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply. I am unable to download the jar file for    import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties and                                                            import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties       which jar i have to use it will be helpfull if i know the link from where can i get it.

Comment: @user2365956 - You can download EclipseLink here:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

Comment: Thanks for quick response                                                             I am facing javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "eclipselink.media-type" is not supported exception

Comment: +Added, using jboss version 5.1.0.GA

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an implicit "feature" of Jettison; it tries to introspect the actual data and figure out what's the best type fit. Better try using some other libraries such as Jackson. Jackson does not try to provide some unnecessary help causing such issues.